# Conda environment in PyCharm

Tags: anaconda

I want to use Anaconda in my PyCharm, and I followed this
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html
but I don't know how should choose the Conda executable.
Thanks for help!